# Carrierwave is appending the store_dir when referencing filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am using the `carrierwave-aws` gem, and I came across an issue while trying to reference my uploaded file name. In my database, I am storing the name of my file as `filename`. When I go to retrieve a `Model.filename` on an erb template, the following is returned:

```
http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/*****/*****/*****/image.png
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue before? I only want to return the raw filename (using the above example, I simply want to return `image.png`). I do not wish to return any other http:// information with it.

This problem is not occurring in the database level, as my file is stored as `image.png` on the db. I also ran a trace of the model object coming back from the database to the rails application, and the result that gets returned is simply `image.png`.

Since the database is returning the proper result, is there something else I should be looking into to determine why the result is being modified on the view level?

To troubleshoot this more, I've tried renaming the `filename` field of my Model, which returned the same problematic result. The result seems to be some kind of combination with the `store_dir` (implemented in the uploader class) plus the filename.

Thanks in advance

Additional Notes:

1. If I return the Model object to the erb template and output it as `<%= obj.inspect %>`, the filename gets returned as `image.png` as expected. However, when I put `<%= obj.filename %>` I'm getting the above problem with an entire url string appended to the name.
2. It seems like mounting the uploader in a model is causing the problems. When I remove the following code from the model, I can see the actual file name, as it appears in my database:

   `mount_uploader :filename, ImagesUploader`

I'm still not sure how to get the file name to return to the erb while having the uploader mounted. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out after inspecting the methods available to my object.

To get the raw file name, I used the following pattern:

`<%= Model.Mounted_Uploader_Name.file.Database_Column %>`

In my specific instance, the code looked like:

`<%= obj.filename.file.filename %>`

This gave me the original filename (and the name that is stored in my database) **image.png** without any extra text appended to it.

Hope this helps.